# What are the settings to allow me to access the Ubuntu IRC from empathy?

Tags: empathy, irc

I want to chat with other Ubuntu-ers but I'm lost on how to do this properly. Do I have to sign up anywhere? Is there only one Ubuntu channel?

Answer (score 4):

## Step by Step Guide to connect to an IRC room

Launch Empathy:

[image]

From the global menu *Edit - Accounts* click the *+* button and change the chat to *IRC* as shown.  Enter your nickname and click the *Login* button.

[image]

After a few seconds you should see the green icon now blinking indicating that you have connected to the server

[image]

Next action is to join a Room.

Enter the room name - all rooms start with *#* e.g. *#ubuntu*.  For a list of Ubuntu rooms, see the link below.

[image]

After joining the chat window should open displaying all chat-room users and the current chat activity.

[image]

---

Useful Link

1. https://wiki.ubuntu.com/IRC/ChannelList

Answer (score 1):

IRC channels of ubuntu are on [Freenode](http://freenode.net) AFAIK. You can use empathy or any other irc client.

`/join #ubuntu`

If you are registered in irc it's better. [Here](http://freenode.net/faq.shtml#nicksetup) is the way on setting up nick on freenode. [Here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/InternetRelayChat) is basic idea of irc on ubuntu.  I recommend [x-chat](http://xchat.org) for irc rather than empathy.

edit: [list of irc channels related to ubuntu](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/IRC/ChannelList)

You don't really have to be registered to irc to use it. But some channels only allow registered users. You can choose a nickname/username and enter. If it is already taken you will be allocated a guest id otherwise you can register the same nickname.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have telepathy-idle installed, and you need to have **at least one non-IRC** account (see [Gnome bug #596086](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=596086) for more details). Then you can connect to the IRC server by creating an account, and join a channel by using the Room > Join room dialog.

[Source](http://live.gnome.org/Empathy/FAQ#How_can_I_connect_to_IRC_in_Empathy_.3F)