# IRC chat on Telepathy

Tags: irc, kde-telepathy

I'm trying to figure out how to get IRC working on Telepathy.

I have installed the `telepathy-idle` package [as suggested here](https://askubuntu.com/a/113952/82943) and [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/113952/82943). I have installed [these telepathy packages](http://paste.ubuntu.com/7607382/)

```
ii  kde-config-telepathy-accounts         0.6.3-0ubuntu1         
ii  kde-telepathy                         0.6.0ubuntu1           
ii  kde-telepathy-approver                0.6.3-0ubuntu1         
ii  kde-telepathy-auth-handler            0.6.3-0ubuntu1         
ii  kde-telepathy-call-ui                 0.6.3-1ubuntu2         
ii  kde-telepathy-contact-list            0.6.3-1fakesync1       
ii  kde-telepathy-data                    0.6.3-1fakesync1ubuntu1
ii  kde-telepathy-desktop-applets         0.6.3-0ubuntu1         
ii  kde-telepathy-filetransfer-handler    0.6.3-0ubuntu1         
ii  kde-telepathy-integration-module      0.6.3-0ubuntu1         
ii  kde-telepathy-minimal                 0.6.0ubuntu1           
ii  kde-telepathy-send-file               0.6.3-1                
ii  kde-telepathy-text-ui                 0.6.3-1                
ii  libtelepathy-farstream2:amd64         0.4.0-3ubuntu1         
ii  libtelepathy-glib0:amd64              0.20.4-1               
ii  libtelepathy-logger3:amd64            0.8.0-1                
ii  libtelepathy-logger-qt4-1:amd64       0.6.0-0ubuntu1         
ii  libtelepathy-qt4-2:amd64              0.9.3-0ubuntu6         
ii  libtelepathy-qt4-farstream2:amd64     0.9.3-0ubuntu6         
ii  telepathy-gabble                      0.18.1-1               
ii  telepathy-haze                        0.6.0-1                
ii  telepathy-idle                        0.1.16-1               
ii  telepathy-logger                      0.8.0-1                
ii  telepathy-mission-control-5           1:5.14.1-1ubuntu6      
ii  telepathy-salut                       0.8.1-1
```

But I'm not getting IRC as an option when add new accounts. I get [these instead](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8c9xL.png).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

KDE telepathy dropped IRC support with the release of version 0.5:

http://martys.typepad.com/blog/2012/08/kde-telepathy-05-released.html

Comment: Thanks. Any recommendations? I've tried Pidgin before.

Comment: There are pure KDE-IRC clients. Konversation and Quassel come to my mind, both of them left good impressions.